# How to close parent view of a child view that's in another controller

Tags: model-view-controller, appcelerator, android-alertdialog, appcelerator-titanium

I have a `props.xml` alloy view and a `prequal.xml` alloy view (which contains a view containing a form), each also have their own respective controllers. The prequal form appears after table data is loaded into `props.xml`.

I needed the prequal form to be a modal window and since Android and iOS treat those differently I had to put the prequal view inside of an AlertDialog for Android and an actual modal window for iOS. So the prequal form is added to the Android AlertDialog, upon `$.UI.create('AlertDialog', {properties});`, via its `androidView` property and added to the iOS window simply by the window's `add(view)` function.

However, the problem lies with that the AlertDialog and Window are defined in `props.js` and I need to be able to close those windows from `prequal.js` after the form is submitted. I tried to use the id associated with those container modal views to close them, but it only closes the actual view containing the form itself, not the parent view containing it as well.

How am I able to close the parent view of their children, when the parent view is defined in a separate controller from that which the child view is defined?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understood the question but you can pass functions as a parameter from one view to another and call a function from a different "controller".

Comment: Sorry, I gave a lot of background information just in case it just may be relevant. Sure most is negligible.

Basically, the parent container views are in props.js and the child views are in prequal.js. I need to be able to call the parent view's close or hide functions from prequal.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `winA` you open a new controller pass over a callback function:

```
function closeA(){
  $.winA.close();
}

Alloy.createController("winB", {
  closeA: closeA
}
```

In `winB` you can call `$.args.closeA()` now to trigger the `closeA()` function in controller `winA`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Working great in my app.